# Highlight "True" Matrix values

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a grid in an Excel table with an x indicating a match between a product and a feature. It's a very large grid, and difficult to read, so in an effort to improve the display, I'd like to have the row for the corresponding products highlighted when I select a feature. And when I select a feature, I'd like to have the row for the corresponding features highlighted.

If my table looks like this:

```
                 Feature 1|Feature 2|Feature 3|
       Product 1|    x    |    x    |         |
       Product 2|    x    |         |    x    |
       Product 3|         |    x    |         |
```

In the above example, selecting Feature 2, for example, would highlight the rows for Product 1 and Product 3. While selecting Product 1, would highlight Feature 1 and Feature 2.

Is this something that can be accomplished with conditional formatting, or is VBA required. I've been trying to use =CELL("address") references, but I can't figure out how to get it to apply to every TRUE product when I select a feature (or TRUE feature when I select a product).

My plan would be to make the interactions dynamic with the following, if I can figure out how to make it work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Application.Calculate
End Sub
```

Comment: how are you doing the selecting? And can you only select one product/feaure at a time?

Comment: And would selecting Product 1 highlight entire columns headed Feature 1 and Feature 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

Me.Cells.Interior.Color = xlNone

If Not Intersect(Range("1:1"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    Set rng = Intersect(Me.UsedRange, Columns(Target.Column))
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In rng
            If cell.Value = "x" Then Me.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 8
        Next cell
    End If
ElseIf Not Intersect(Range("A:A"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    Set rng = Intersect(Me.UsedRange, Rows(Target.Row))
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In rng
            If cell.Value = "x" Then Me.Cells(1, cell.Column).Interior.ColorIndex = 8
        Next cell
    End If
Else
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: aha... that answers my questions! Nice

Comment: This is great, Scott - thanks! I'm sure I'd figure it out eventually, but what I'm really hoping to do is highlight the label itself. So "Feature 1" or "Product 2", for example, would be highlighted, as opposed to the x on the grid. I imagine I change the "Cell.Interior.ColorIndex" to accomplish that? Can you help me with the appropriate references?

Comment: @JoeyJoJo see edit. remember to mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer if this works.